# Get working directory of the parent shell from a child process

Tags: bash

I'm calling `/location2/script2.sh` from `/location1/script1.sh`. Is there a method to figure out `location1` from `script2.sh`?

`bash /location2/script2.sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use `$PWD` or `pwd`.

If you call `/location2/script2.sh` from `/location1/script1.sh`, then the current working directory of `script2.sh` will always be `/location1`, not `/location2`.

Comment: Thanks! Should've thought of this.